# custom color for handout

Tags: beamer, color

I want to print text I put in \only{TEXT} in another color, so I will spot my personal notes faster in the talk.

What command do I need for this, please?

I was thinking about creating a new command printing something only in the handout and coloring it. Is there already something similar?

my preamble so far is:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Goettingen}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%   \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\mode<handout>{
  \usetheme{default}
%  \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black!5}
  \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=2.5mm]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply put

```
\def\myhighlight#1{\only<handout>{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
```

into your preamble and the use `\myhighlight{this}` to print *this*, that only shows up in the handout, in red.